# Querying the Last Value in Related Table of Many-to-Many Relationship in Django

Tags: django, django-queryset

As a newbie programmer I have following two models, where both models are connected to each other in a many-to-many setting.

Imagine there are thousands of assignments made for hundreds of tasks, some of "Take" type, some of "Drop" time and at various times.

My goal is to query the either of the following conditions :

- Find all tasks with no assignment OR
- Find all tasks whose latest assignment is of "Drop" type

```
class Tasks(models.Model):
    task_message = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    task_assignment = models.ManyToManyField('Assignments',blank=True,related_name="assignments")

class Assignments(models.Model):
    assignee = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=False,null=True,related_name="assigned_user")
    Type = (
        (TAKE, 'Assigned To'),
        (DROP, 'Dropped From'),
        (FORWARD, 'Forwarded To'),
    )
    assignment_type = models.CharField(choices=Type, default=TAKE,max_length=20)
    assignment_update_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Answer (score -1):

The answer is in the documentation: Q() functions are the answer to your problem as you're trying to create an SQL OR-statement. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I spent seious time on different trials with Q()s, yet was unable to come up with what I aim for. Any detailed help will be highly appreciated.